# How does one set the height of a textarea row in CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I want to alter the height of a single row in a textarea. So I'm looking for something like `row-height:20px;` If that exists that would be great. As I'm guessing that it does not, what do I do? Thanks in advance.

I want a textarea that is a single row but that has a height of 20 px. I cannot use the css height function to set this.

Comment: For your second question: illustrate what you are trying to accomplish better and people (including me) will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `line-height`:

```
textarea { line-height: 2em; }
```

Comment: May I offer [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7CYhX/)? *One* day I'll remember: *post first*, demonstrate *second*... =/

Comment: I tried this but it seems to keep the same height for the textarea and shift my text out of the box. Ideas?

Comment: Ahh i misread question to say "One row in textarea to be 20px line height". Nice!

Comment: @thatidiotguy I changed it so that it was a tad more clear :)

Comment: I read up on this line-height thing and I know that it is the correct way to do this so why is it not working?

Comment: Well crap. Just found that firefox always adds a second line and that your way is working perfectly. Thanks for the help man!