# How to adjust the new line height in a textarea

Tags: html, css

I am loading data into a textarea. I need to have each property on a new line. The issue I have is the spacing in between the lines. 
This

```
<label>Customer&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;</label>
<textarea>{{currentItem.CustomerName}}
{{currentItem.CustomerAddress}}</textarea>
```

returns this:

> CompanyName
>
> 495 Crystal Street

I need it to have normal line spacing.

> CompanyName
>   495 Crystal Street

Comment: Please share your CSS and the *rendered* output.

Comment: use CSS `line-height` method in your `textarea` styles

Comment: +1 to @LinkinTED's comment - the rendered output may show that <span> or even <p> tags are being added dynamically, in which case just adding a line-height value to the CSS may be inadequate to fix the issue.

Comment: @Candlejack spans and paragraphs would render as HTML tags inside of textarea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do this in your CSS:

```
textarea {
  line-height: *what ever you want*;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the `line-height` with CSS, this question has been [answered already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544411/how-does-one-set-the-height-of-a-textarea-row-in-css)

```
textarea {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

or you could do it inline::

```
<label>Customer&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;</label>
<textarea style="line-height: 1;">{{currentItem.CustomerName}}
{{currentItem.CustomerAddress}}</textarea>
```